# Cordova - how to read and write s file in the web application folder

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, cordova-3

I am with Cordova and JQuery to build an Android App.

I have a json file in /www/data/my file.json, and I need to read this file into front end index.html on the device ready event, also to overwrite this file as well from a button click as well.

Can anyone point me a direction what object of the Cordova  file plugin I should use? An example would be really appreciated.

Comment: Do not add spaces to filenames in your Cordova App, unless you are looking for trouble...

Answer (score 0):

The direction is the [cordova-plugin-file](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/), but good luck modifying files from the app package, which is impossible as far as I know... no app cannot rewrite itself that way.

To keep small JSON data, you should use [localStorage](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.1.0/cordova/storage/localstorage/localstorage.html), this is the easiest way and it does not require plugins. Refer to the localStorage limits before though.